# PHP Script submitting blank information to my SQL Database, not passing the inputted info through

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am attempting to learn some html/php. I have created a form that i want to submit info to a MYSQL database. I have created the database and created the forms etc. The problem i have is that when the form is submitted it is submitting blank info to the table. If i replace the variables with "123" that is posted to the database so it seems to not be pulling the info from the index to the form. Cannot work out why it is posting blank info, any suggestions? My index page is :

```html
<html> 
    <head>

    <style type="text/css">
    .sms_image
    {
                    text-align: right-side;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="//www.powr.io/powr.js" external-type="html"></script> 
     <div class="powr-hit-counter" id="b6cbafa4_1487845849" align="right-side"  </div>
    <p class="sms_image"><img src="http://images.knowledge-    action.co.uk/sites/default/files/sms_logo_short_0.jpg" height="100" width="170">    </img><br></p>
    <title> Simply Mail Solutions </title>
    </head>
    <body     background="https://media.licdn.com/media/AAEAAQAAAAAAAAYCAAAAJDQ1YTQ0MTNlLWI2MD    ItNGYxOS05MjMxLWFmOTZhNjgyMjNhMA.png">
    <font color="white">Welcome to a random test page</font>
    <br> 
    <br>
    <form action="yourform-processor.php" name="FirstAttempt" method="POST"     enctype="text/plain">
    <font face="impact" color="white">Client ID:</font>
    <input type="text" name="client_id" ><br>
    <br>
    <font face="impact"color="white">Domain:</font>
    <input type="text" name="domain"><br>
    <br>
    <font face="impact" color="white">Comments:</font>
    <input type="textarea" name="comment" style="width: 568px; height: 273px">          <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
    <br>
    <br>
    </form>
    <footer>
      <p>Posted by: Dylan Cunliffe</p>
    </footer>
    </body>
    </html>"
```

---

My PHP form that posts to the database is:

```html
 <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username   = "Dylanc";
$password   = "xxx";
$dbname     = "FirstAttempt";

$errors = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


//first validate user input
if (empty($_POST['client_id'])) {

    echo "enter client id";
    $errors++;
} else {

    $client_id = $_POST["client_id"];
}


if (empty($_POST['domain'])) {

    echo "enter domain";
    $errors++;
} else {

    $domain = $_POST["domain"];
}

if (empty($_POST['comment'])) {

    echo "enter comment";
    $errors++;
} else {

    $comment = $_POST["comment"];
}


if ($errors <= 0) {
    //fields are not empty save to db
    $sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO FirstAttempt (client_id,domain,comment) VALUES(?,?,?) ");
    $sql->bind_param("ssss", $client_id, $domain, $comment);

    if ($sql->execute()) {

        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {

        //report bacck the error
    }
}



$conn->close();
?>
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: your problem is you are mixing mysqli_* and mysql_*

Comment: The best suggestion for you would be to not use MySQL_ anymore and learn to use Prepared PHP statement with PDO or if you prefer MySQL_ way with MYSQLI !

Answer (score 0):

Best and simple clean solution use mysqli prepared statments, or use pdo prepared statements.

**MYSQLI Prepared :**

```
 <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username   = "Dylanc";
$password   = "xxxx";
$dbname     = "FirstAttempt";

$errors = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


//first validate user input
if (empty($_POST['client_id'])) {

    echo "enter client id";
    $errors++;
} else {

    $client_id = $_POST["client_id"];
}


if (empty($_POST['domain'])) {

    echo "enter domain";
    $errors++;
} else {

    $domain = $_POST["domain"];
}

if (empty($_POST['comment'])) {

    echo "enter comment";
    $errors++;
} else {

    $comment = $_POST["comment"];
}


if ($errors <= 0) {
    //fields are not empty save to db
    $sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO FirstAttempt (client_id,domain,comment) VALUES(?,?,?) ");
    $sql->bind_param("ssss", $client_id, $domain, $comment);

    if ($sql->execute()) {

        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {

        //report bacck the error
    }
}



$conn->close();
?>
```

**with PDO prepared statements**

```
  <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username   = "Dylanc";
$password   = "xxxx";
$dbname     = "FirstAttempt";
$charset    = 'utf8';


$dsn = "mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname;charset=$charset";
$opt = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
        ];


$conn = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $opt);
//first validate user input



//first validate user input
if (empty($_POST['client_id'])) {

    echo "enter client id";
    $errors++;
} else {

    $client_id = $_POST["client_id"];
}


if (empty($_POST['domain'])) {

    echo "enter domain";
    $errors++;
} else {

    $domain = $_POST["domain"];
}

if (empty($_POST['comment'])) {

    echo "enter comment";
    $errors++;
} else {

    $comment = $_POST["comment"];
}


if ($errors <= 0) {

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO FirstAttempt(client_id, domain, comment) VALUES(?,?,?)");
    if ($stmt->execute(array(
        $client_id,
        $domain,
        $comment
    ))) {

        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {

        // error in your code.
    }

}

?>
```

> **NB: If we want to insert any data from external sources (like user input), it is very important that the data is sanitized and
>   validated.**

**Update :**

```
<form action="yourform-processor.php" name="FirstAttempt" method="POST">
<font face="impact" color="white">Client ID:</font>
<input type="text" name="client_id" ><br>
<br>
<font face="impact"color="white">Domain:</font>
<input type="text" name="domain"><br>
<br>
<font face="impact" color="white">Comments:</font>
<input type="textarea" name="comment" style="width: 568px; height: 273px">          <br>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
<br>
<br>
</form>
```

**yourform-processor.php**

```
 <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username   = "Dylanc";
$password   = "xxx";
$dbname     = "FirstAttempt";

$errors = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //first validate user input
    if (empty($_POST['client_id'])) {

        echo "enter client id";
        $errors++;
    } else {

        $client_id = $_POST['client_id'];
    }


    if (empty($_POST['domain'])) {

        echo "enter domain";
        $errors++;
    } else {

        $domain = $_POST['domain'];
    }

    if (empty($_POST['comment'])) {

        echo "enter comment";
        $errors++;
    } else {

        $comment = $_POST['comment'];
    }


    if ($errors <= 0) {
        //fields are not empty save to db
        $sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO FirstAttempt (client_id,domain,comment) VALUES(?,?,?) ");
        $sql->bind_param("ssss", $client_id, $domain, $comment);

        if ($sql->execute()) {

            echo "New record created successfully";
        } else {

            //report bacck the error
        }
    }



    $conn->close();

}
?>
```

Comment: Okay so a rookie error i assume... scrap mysql and use mysqli atleast then. I have tried the MYSQLI Prepared code you suggested but still inputs a blank entry to the db :/

Comment: are you sure that the inputs are set and not empty? if yes, whats on your error log?

Comment: @DylanCunliffe add this line on top of the code `ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);`  then tell me what error you getting

Comment: try second method. do u get anything in the db?

Comment: Helpful little line of code that, i get this: Notice: Undefined index: client_id in /var/www/vhosts/dylan.simplyms.com/httpdocs/yourform-processor.php on line 17 Notice: Undefined index: domain in /var/www/vhosts/dylan.simplyms.com/httpdocs/yourform-processor.php on line 18 Notice: Undefined index: comments in /var/www/vhosts/dylan.simplyms.com/httpdocs/yourform-processor.php on line 19 Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in /var/www/vhosts/dylan.simplyms.com/httpdocs/yourform-processor.php on line 23

Comment: that means you did not check if the inputs are set and not empty.

Comment: I thought if (isset($_POST['value']))    
{    
          // Instructions if $_POST['value'] exist    
}    does that?

Comment: I've update both my answers, and you also mixing $_GET with $_POST

Comment: **Undefined index: domain**  Your domain is `$domain=$_GET['domain']` instead of `$_POST` please use the updated answers I have

Comment: I was aware i was mixing them, i was trying if it was working as GET instead and not changed it back. I have tried the updated version and now get this enter client identer domainenter comment

Comment: that means you have left those fields empty, you need to enter values

Comment: I didn't leave them empty...all boxes had values in.

Comment: I have updated both sets of code in the original post :) Cheers for your help so far

Comment: Did you update your form as well? I added a name attribute to the submit button

Comment: You must be doing something wrong, please check your server error log

Comment: [Mon Feb 27 12:06:12 2017] [error] [client 185.20.5.170] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/dylan.simplyms.com/httpdocs/httpdocs

Comment: You are probably doing something wrong...  which file is that that does not exits>

Comment: Also get 
[Mon Feb 27 11:49:34 2017] [warn] [client 77.44.73.21] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in /var/www/vhosts/dylan.simplyms.com/httpdocs/yourform-processor.php on line 50, referer: http://dylan.simplyms.com/index.php
[Mon Feb 27 12:06:12 2017]

Comment: Please ask a new question, with your latest code and add the error log messages